# Why this MongooseDB population method doesn't work?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I wanted to create a database for MTG combos, and doing something very simple like this, using Mongoose and MLab: We have two schemas, Combo and Card, and two instances of a Card model associated with an instance of a Combo model. When I try to populate the combos of the cards with the name of such combo, it doesn't work and it still shows the ID instead of the name.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose') ;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://wernerbusch:xxxx!h@ds115340.mlab.com:15340/wernercito');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var comboSchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    cards : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Card'}],
    type : ["infinite mana", "infinite damage", "draw library", "lethal damage", "storm", "graveyard"]
});

var cardSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    colour:["U","R","B","W","G","C"],
    combos: [{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Combo'}]
})

var Combo = mongoose.model("Combo",comboSchema);
var Card = mongoose.model("Card",cardSchema);

var PanderBurst = new Combo({
    name:"PanderBurst",
    type:'lethal damage'
})

PanderBurst.save(function(err){
    if (err) console.log( err)

    var SaprolingBurst = new Card({
        name: "Saproling Burst", 
        colour:["G", "R"],
        combos : PanderBurst._id
    })

    var Pandemonium = new Card({
        name: "Pandemonium",
        colour:["R"],
        combos: PanderBurst._id
    })

    SaprolingBurst.save(function(err){
        if (err) console.log( err)
    });

    Pandemonium.save(function(err){
        if (err) console.log( err)
    })
});

Card.find().populate('combos', 'name').exec(function(err,cards){
    if (err) console.log (err);
})
```

After this code is executed, nothing changes in the cards documents.

Comment: Let me know if I've answered your question.

Comment: not really sorry :( I still don't understand how to replace the id of the combo with its name, or how to display all cards from a combo.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
 Card.find().populate({path: "comboes", select: "name"})
                      .exec((err,cards)=>{
                               if (err) console.log (err);
                               console.log(cards);
                            });
```

Using an object has always worked for me.

Update:
  you also have:

```
comboes: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Combo'}
```

in your schema 
and `combos` in your populate. 
Final Update: 
  Populate is used when you make a query. Populating a schema during create isn't good practice because it causes duplication, so call populate with each query.

Comment: to verify, you are getting the correct id back from the query, just not populated results?

Comment: Kramer Yes, the ID is correct, but is just not populated.

Comment: two things: Are you just trying to return it populated or are you trying to save it populated? The second one defeats the purpose of populate. The second thing is, does it work with the combos typo fixed?

Comment: ohh I see. So I can't modify it in the database? I thought that was populate did. I guess I just didn't understand what populate does. So population only works locally but doesn't modify the database?

Comment: Yes, you're using populate so that you don't have to store the data twice other than id. When you retrieve the data, you use populate to do that and then return the populated data rather than storing the name twice or rather than storing the card twice. It helps when your data changes too.

Comment: what you're doing makes sense, just do it when a query takes place.

Comment: I tried doing this but the result is that the name is added next to the ID, like this:
 `combos: { _id: 5aee2d94c40b1f06c496faca, name: 'PanderBurst' }`,
 instead of replacing it. So afterwards if I try to do something like `Card.find({'combos':'PanderBurst'}).exec(function(err,cards){
 console.log("cards that Panderburst uses:" + cards)
})`, this doesnt work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170437/discussion-between-david-kamer-and-werner-german-busch).

Comment: So I should have two different files, one for creating the models, and another for making queries? That way I am sure that I finished creating the models and objects before making a query.

Comment: What do I do once I made a query?